# How to edit files line by line and inserting text into document based on condition?

Tags: python, file

I have a file called words.txt. It is 5 rows of letters:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I would like for python to read in this file line by line. If `b` is followed by `c`, I would like to insert 3 zeros, i.e. `0`, `0`, `0`, and append them as 3 lines under `b` in the same file (or a different one). The desired result would be a new text file called words_edited.txt that looks like this:

```
a
b
0
0
0
c
d
```

This is my code so far:

```
def function():
    infile = open('words.txt')
    outfile = open('words_edited.txt', 'w')

    for line in infile:
        if line == 'b' and next(infile) == 'c':
            outfile.write('0\n0\n0\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to actually read the lines so you need to replace `infile = open('words.txt')` with

```py
infile = open('words.txt')
letters = infile.readlines()
```

or better yet use `.read().splitlines()` to get rid of the trailing `\n` characters after each letter. If you print the infile after the modification you should see a list that looks like this `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` if you went for the latter option. Now that you are working with a list you can simply iterate over it adding the elemnts to another list and checking if the current letter is b and if it's followed by c and if it is adding the zeros to the list as well. Once that's done you can join the list elements into a string and write it to the outfile. Also don't forget to close the files once you're done using them. The resulting code would look something like this:

```py
def function():
    infile = open('words.txt')
    letters = infile.read().splitlines()

    outfile = open('words_edited.txt', 'w')

    res = []

    n = len(letters)
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(letters[i])
        if letters[i] == 'b' and i + 1 != n and letters[i+1] == 'c':
            res.append('0\n0\n0')

    outfile.write('\n'.join(res))

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function()
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do it but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible so you can better understand it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are actually not any trailing \n's in the document, I just wanted to illustrate that the characters were on separate lines. Does this mean I would just not use :    outfile.write('\n'.join(res))?

Comment: If they are on seperate lines there are `\n`'s in the document but you don't see them as `\n`, you see them as the actual new lines. So if you want the letters in the resulting file to be on separate lines you still need `utfile.write('\n'.join(res))`